# Local Variables in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've read online that if you use local variables in stored procedures instead of the input variables then the stored procedure is optimized as if it was using the hint OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN. How exactly does that happen? Also, what's a good practice in general: use input variables directly or create local variables and assign the input variables to them?

Comment: Could you include an [mcve] with the actual output (query plan) and what you think it should have been (expected output)? You can use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Search the internet for "parameter sniffing" to learn why variables behave like `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN` (unless you use the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint. Like just about all things SQL Server, the answer to good practice is "it depends".

Comment: Thank you so much guys! Appreciate your responses. I'll go and read the articles you guys mentioned.

Comment: probably helpful to know that "input variables" are properly known as parameters - this will make searching for articles much easier.

Answer (score 7):

### post it

From my blog post [Yet Another Post About Local Variables](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/yet-another-post-about-local-variables/)

> In a stored procedure (and even in ad hoc queries or within dynamic
> SQL, like in the examples linked above), if you declare a variable
> within that code block and use it as a predicate later, you will get
> either a fixed guess for cardinality, or a less-confidence-inspiring
> estimate than when the histogram is used.
>
> The local variable effect discussed in the rest of this post produces
> the same behavior as the OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN hint, or [executing
> queries with sp_prepare](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/sp_prepare-isnt-good-sp_executesql-performance/).
>
> That estimate will be based on the number of rows in the table, and
> the “All Density” of the column multiplied together, for single
> equality predicates. The process for [multiple predicates](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/cardinality-estimation-for-multiple-predicates) depends on
> which cardinality estimation model you’re using.

The guess you get depends on what kind of predicate you use.

Equality predicates multiply table cardinality by column selectivity:

[image: NUTS]

And inequality predicates use different fixed percentages of table cardinality depending on which cardinality estimation model you're using.

[image: NUTS]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in existing comments, this is usually due to parameter sniffing when deciding what cached plan to use or when to produce a new one. It is often a cause (not always the cause, and this is not the only symptom) of “slow in the app, fast in SSMS” problems.

Erland Sommarskog has a nice detailed but readable run-down of the issue, that gets updated when he finds (or people report) new different edge cases, at https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html
He includes other possible causes, potential fixes, and when they might/not be useful. There are also a couple of videos on youtube of him talking about the subject (though not in the same breadth & depth) at conferences & other events, that you might like to find if you understand/retain new information better that way.

One thing to be careful of when using tricks to force multiple plans to avoid sniffing issues, is that in some cases you can end up filling your plan cache with lots of examples which perform identically resulting in less space to cache more useful plans for other parts of your applications. You can also cause yourself new
performance issues, when compiling a plan every time wastes more time than using less optimal stored plans would. So don't be tempted to prematurely optimise by trying to account for the possibility of parameter sniffing issues that have not yet made themselves apparent, just keep the concept in mind for when diagnosing future performance issues that fit these patterns.